# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method' when im using model.fit(X_train,y_train)

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

```py
data = pd.read_csv('carsverzeo.csv')
X = cars.loc[:,['HP','Wt','AM']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=100)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please  take a moment to check tips on how to ask questions  : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is `y` ? what is `X_train.shape`, `y_train.shape` ?